# Possibly wrong transaction status in Shopware 6 mails?

Tags: shopware6

All e-mail templates in Shopware 6 reference the transactions payment name and current state by using the first collection entry `order.transactions.first.paymentMethod.translated.name` and
`order.transactions.first.stateMachineState.translated.name`.

Is the transaction sorting for e-mails different that the default sorting by createdAt?
Because according to all code examples I have found so far [(e.g. AccountOrderPageLoader)](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/c8f04a4ef6189f5b87767bd52b27310635204e2d/src/Storefront/Page/Account/Order/AccountOrderPageLoader.php#L138) the transactions are normally sorted by createdAt.

Based on the sortings I would expect e-mails to show a wrong payment method if the customer switches the payment method after ordering.

So my question is:
Shouldn't all e-mail templates reference the **last** entry of the transactions collection to really show the latest state? Or is the sorting for e-mails changed somewhere else?

Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a valid concern but given the standard procedures shouldn't become an issue. This is because when using the `StateMachineRegistry` to transition from one state to another, the existing state entity is [being updated](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/027efc5bd32b6e91475784e874f6157fc8a76fe5/src/Core/System/StateMachine/StateMachineRegistry.php#L218) instead of a new one being inserted. So if the transition model is being used as it is intended, there should only be one state per combination of order and payment/delivery method that gets updated, with the former states being persisted as `state_machine_history` entities to retrace state changes.

Technically however, given that the associations are instances of `OneToManyAssociationField`, it is obviously possible to persist multiple entities of `order_transaction` or `order_delivery` per order when using the corresponding repositories. I think the reason for this relation model being used was to, in the future, potentially allow multiple delivery/payment methods when placing a single order. However this currently isn't implemented which is why it is important to use the proper services to transition between states as explained.

Comment: Unfortunately in following situation this is not the case:
<br>
1. Customer orders something via invoice<br>
2. Customer changes the payment method to PayPal and pays<br>
<br>
After this $order->getTransactions() has twoi elements and the last element ist the paid PayPal transaction.

Comment: If that is the case please report this as a bug with a step by step instruction on how to reproduce it. In that case it won't matter if the last or first data set of the collection is spliced off, when there is no definite sorting in place. It will arbitrary which one of the transaction states will be spliced off anyways.